Apple Wallet pass personalization not working - Unable to Personalize Pass
We create NFC enabled wallet passes for Apple. We now want to add a feature where users can personalize their own pass following the Rewards Enrolling: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/PassPersonalization.html
This all works, we create an NFC pass and on the back of the pass we now see a button called 'Add Personal Info'. When we click this we get an error message: Unable to personlise Pass - The pass cannot currenlty be personalized:
enter image description here
The documentation states, that when a user clicks 'Add Personal Info',  Wallet will send the following POST request: POST request to webServiceURL/version/passes/passTypeIdentifier/serialNumber/personalize
This response (handled by us) should return the personalization fields, but we never receive it.
We never receive other requests:
/personalization/v1/devices/xxxxxx/registrations/:passID/000001
But that request is for 'after' the personlize request (we get the same POST request when we update a pass from our server for example for a loyalty program when changing points.
We do have an example pass from an external source, which is working:
enter image description here
This is what we want to show after the user is clicking 'Add Personal Info' button, the fields are coming from personalization.json in our pass package.
When we unzip the pkpass file, which is working, we see exaclty the same pass.json, personalization.json and other files like we have. So my assumption is that the issue is somehwere on our server or certificates (yes we do have the NFC pass entitlement).

Use new certificates just in case
Update our server with /personalized
add extra logs
unzip the working pkpass and copy the fields only adding our team identifier and webserviceurl

